# Typescript function that accepts array of strings and returns object with given strings as keys

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How could one properly typescript the following method:

```
const getVars = (vars: string[]) => {
  const data = [
    {
      "someId": "28",
      "someAttr": "2",
    },
    {
      "someId": "43",
      "someOtherAttr": "3",
    },
    {
      "someOtherId": "32",
      "someAttr": "4",
    }
  ] // an array containing some data

  const result = vars.reduce((acc, _var) => ({
    ...acc,
    ...data.reduce((acc, acc) => ({
      ...acc,
      [...acc[_var], curr[_var]]
    }, {})
  }), {})

  return result
}
```

usage:

```
const { someId, someAttr } = getVars(['someId', 'someAttr'])
```

output:
`someId: ['28', '43'], someAttr: ['2', '4']`

I'd like to typescript `getVars` so the return type would reflect given parameters, for example, if I pass ['someId'] as parameter, the typescript would know the function returns an object with key 'someId'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can type this kinda-sorta strictly or very strictly.  It depends on how much information you know up front (do you know the keys of the elements of `data`?) and how crazy you want to be.  Your `data` here is an `array` of `object`s with `string` keys.  Are the values always `string`?  Or do they just happen to be in this example?

For the kinda-sorta strict approach, I am assuming that the values are always `string` and that `data` has type `Record<string, string>[]`.

We want to know the specific string values that we passed to `getVars`, so we will use a generic `T extends string`.  We return an object that has those specific strings `T` as keys and the values are an array of strings.  So the return type is `Record<T, string[]>`.

When you are building an object through `reduce()` you need to use `as` to assert the type of the final object.

```
const getVars = <T extends string>(vars: T[]): Record<T, string[]> => {
    return vars.reduce((acc, _var) => ({
        ...acc,
        [_var]: data.map(o => o[_var]).filter(v => v !== undefined)
    }), {} as Record<T, string[]>);
}

const { someId, someAttr } = getVars(['someId', 'someAttr'])
console.log(someId, someAttr);
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQyggXDASgU1AJzgHmhwEswBzAGhiNLID4BtAXRgF4YGAoGHmAb268hAIgggAtpgCScYWmEAmABzCKgoT1ETMAQShQccmItXqYAXzVCBG3lskyjwgCwBmU7c1jJAeSgALTBw9Ayd3K15LMxtPe0w-QJxHeVcFD1jvXX1DeWd0nnNOFgB6YpgEMHKcHAQATxhQMGRSWmpteCQETm7G6BgyTCgANQQcCDYYfAAVGEwADyhMMDhxmnI6AAoAN1GINCnmAEo0LFwCKao1smY6NluYnhxBgFccSp2xgDonuGfgTA2GwQwGAVAA%20h9DncYBsHhpPgjgaCzEIGBDRkw0IhkJ9xAgAA4bEDQkBoj5MQ6fABmxAANoscNtoVsYABCVjsZ7LTA0sCYOCHMzmQ5UPjmcrjU4gPDTS4GWg3Q4Abk4hU4vVgfDaDjgl20IRwFgmA2Guw2DAA5JkZBaqFb9dkLRT1eAxLTMJ9aSAyBtrbrtVkDMrOKUQM8oPjw2g-WhLcpbTALW4nXrJAbYxaFAmk07uqUpBa4DBacQANaYGBQYlQWr4zAQYAkfGwE0jMZtSuBGBPKCvSo1uswADuYdpRaeVPdwBbxC2Sxg%20NGCEkDIgVCp0tmc2X%20PdVGIVJgUgXCAg40tfqdEpPNRXQSoAQrA-rjeIzeHo6LpbAICHnYrVJctOxDgN2LxvOMFQwCAABGABW2CwEOxABDA5b1PaOoWp8QA)

Comment: That is excellent. As for the return type, the record returns string key and possibly string or function as value: `someId: [string, string], someFunc: [func, func]`. Is there a way to type it strictly? I guess the typings of objects values should be given upfront to the `getVars`

Answer (score -1):

```
const data = [
    {
      "someId": "28",
      "someAttr": "2",
    },
    {
      "someId": "43",
      "someOtherAttr": "3",
    },
    {
      "someOtherId": "32",
      "someAttr": "4",
    }
  ];

const getVars = (data, vars) => {
  return data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    Object.keys(curr).filter(key => vars.includes(key)).forEach(
      key => acc[key] = [...(acc[key] || []), curr[key]],
    );
    
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

console.log(getVars(data, ['someId', 'someAttr']));
```

Comment: This is a typescript question by there are no types anywhere in your code.